# Como fazer uma busca por palavras similares (erros ortograficos) no MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select, operador-like

Estou montando um sistema de busca usando Mysql e PHP, com um fomulário no método _GET.

Eu queria montar um sistema que se a pessoa digitar errado, o site consiga "corrigir" a palavra, ou sugerir a palavra correta.

A única forma que pensei é ter tipo uma tabela de relação, ex:

```
tabela_relacoes
termo|variacao
maçã | macan
maçã |amaçã
```

Existe alguma forma melhor de se fazer isso?

Minha busca atualmente está assim:

```
SELECT *
FROM cadastros
WHERE titulo LIKE '%termo%'
```

onde termo é fornecido pela váriavel $_GET['termo'] na busca em php

Comment: Nunca precisei utilizar, mas pesquisa por [full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) que é o que tu precisa.

Comment: legal, to dando uma pesquisada nisso, vlw